# bash and if with multiple logical operands

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I am trying to check if 2 variables are empty or not defined at the same time in bash. If that is the case, no user password will be changed.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    read -s  -p "Enter root password: " rootpass1
    echo
    read -s  -p "Enter root password again: " rootpass2
    echo
    if  [[-z "$rootpass1"] && [-z "$rootpass2"]]
    then
         echo "Password will not be changed"
         break
    else
        if [ $rootpass1 != $rootpass2 ]
        then
            echo "Passwords are not identical"
        else
            echo "user:$rootpass1" | chpasswd
            break
        fi
    fi
done
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
script.sh: line 8: [: missing `]'
```

Any clue?

Comment: It is a terrible idea to write your own version of the [passwd command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/passwd). Especially since even after debugging it is still broken [because you are still using](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32297965/282912) `if [ $rootpass1 != $rootpass2 ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
#!/bin/bash
read -s  -p "Enter root password: " rootpass1
echo
read -s  -p "Enter root password again: " rootpass2
echo

if  [[ -z "$rootpass1" && -z "$rootpass2" ]]
then
    echo "Password will not be changed"
else
    if [[ "$rootpass1" != "$rootpass2" ]]
    then
        echo "Passwords are not identical"
    else
        echo "user:$rootpass1" | chpasswd
    fi
fi
```

Note that the whitespace around `[[` and `]]` is important. I also think `||` would be just a little bit better for your first test: don't do anything if *either* of the passwords is empty (since either they are both empty, or they are not identical, so you spare some effort).

Comment: Sorry !! I am new and learning !!! Did what you told me and posted my very own answer below !!! Thanks

Comment: @FedeKrum it's OK, you'll get to grips with it in time:) You just misunderstood me, I tried to explain again below your answer. Eventually we should have: 1. your question, edited to contain the final solution **as well as the original question**, 2. the answers by Steve and me, 3. none of our chatty comments:) I'll remove mine, like this one, when we reach a final conclusion.

Comment: @AndrasDeak No, that's wrong.  The question should contain just the question.  The accepted answer should be more or less what the OP ended up using; sometimes the OP will accept one of the answers but still post one of her/his own just to clarify how it was adapted.

Comment: @tripleee, I totally agree, but OP seems adamant on including the final solution one way or the other... My proposed solution is already a compromise. (Their original solution was changing the question to include only the final code...)

Answer (score 2):

You need double brackets around both tests, like this:

```
if  [[ -z "$rootpass1" ]] && [[ -z "$rootpass2" ]]
```

Comment: `if  [[ -z "$rootpass1" &&  -z "$rootpass2" ]]` works fine too (tested in ksh). Good luck to all.

Comment: You are right !!  It worked, so I edited the question with the right script.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the script with the sugestions and it did work !!!
Thanks !!! I will give points for that when I get able to do that.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    read -s  -p "Enter admin password: " rootpass1
    echo
    read -s  -p "Enter admin password again: " rootpass2
    echo
    if  [[ -z "$rootpass1" ]] && [[ -z "$rootpass2" ]]
    then
        echo "Password will not be changed. Both are empty."
        echo
        break
    else
        if [[ $rootpass1 != $rootpass2 ]]
        then
                echo "Passwords are not identical. Try again."
                echo
        else
                echo "root:$rootpass1" | chpasswd
                echo "Password changed."
                echo
                break
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Getting better. You don't need to add an answer of your own as I have already done so:) But if you want to include the final solution still, then edit your original question and add the final version of the working code, with a proper separation from the original question. You should put a meaningful header in between.

Comment: This still lacks proper quoting in the second `if`.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable

Comment: For consistency, you probably want to use `[[` everywhere, instead of mixing `[` and `[[`.